# Reading error from the file in java

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jakarta-ee, compiler-errors

I wrote the following program reading number of computers from text фалйа, containing a prime number

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFromFile {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int CountComputers=0;
        try {
        DataInputStream ConfigFile = new DataInputStream( new 
         FileInputStream("D:\\HadoopFolder\\ReadFromFile\\src\\countcomputers.txt"));
        CountComputers=ConfigFile.readInt();
        ConfigFile.close(); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //CountComputers=ConfigFile.readInt();
        System.out.println("Количество компьютеров равно "+CountComputers);
    }

}
```

As a result I received the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at ReadFromFile.main(ReadFromFile.java:16)
```

Whether also I have a question surely it is necessary to conclude reading from the file in try... expect (in one project emphasized red, and in other too on java (it was some other kind) no). I am a beginner in Java therefore a request to treat with understanding.

Comment: what are the contents of countcomputers.txt. i tried to replicate your code. it runs fine. but i am not sure what are you expecting oout of it.

Comment: @BhanuKaushik , number 4 is written in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

java.io.EOFException
- This exception is mainly used by data input streams to signal end of stream. Note that many other input operations return a special value on end of stream rather than throwing an exception.

I believe there are no int present in the file you are reading
Try this 
`CountComputers=Integer.valueOf(ConfigFile.readLine());`

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any issue with your code (as long as your input file contains data). Any way Java has nice AP (`java.util.Scanner` )to read data from file ( from JDK1.5 onwards) .

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("countcomputers.txt"));
if(scanner.hasNext()){
    data= scanner.nextInt();
}
else{
        System.out.println(" No Data found");
}
```

This logic also takes care of `EOFException`